# How to avoid converting date to string when object cames from web API

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class:

> ```
> export class TestClass  {
>         paymentDate: Date; 
> }
> ```

When I try to get an object of this class from some server API, the paymentDate field comes as a string so I can't call for this field .getDate() method.
Is there any possibility to avoid this converting?

UPD.
Here is an example:

[image]

Also I would like to notice, server returns a model like this:

```
public class TestClass
    {
        public DateTime? PaymentDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: In what string format does the date come? Can you give example of what you get from the server API?

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the code you aren't showing to us, but you can just use `Date("2018-07-26T23:00:00")`

Answer (score 2):

I am a little confused if you need help on the server side (looks like c#) or the client side (javascript)

Either way then one way is to write a custom setter or have a map function that maps the data from web api to the class.

I haven't tested this code, but the idea is that to have a setter that parses the date.

server/c# code:

```
public class TestClass {
  private DateTime paymentdate
  public DateTime? PaymentDate {
    get { 
      return paymentdate
    }
    set {
      this.paymentdate = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't tested the C# code, but it should get you in the right direction.

On the client side (javascript/typescript) you could do something like this.

```
export class TestClass {
  private _paymentdate: Date;

  get paymentDate(): Date {
    return this._paymentDate
  }

  set paymentDate(value: string) {
    this._paymentDate = new Date(value);
  }
}
```

Here the parsing happens in the setter. So you avoid in your code where you retrieve the value.

You would then do something like:

```
let myTestClass = new TestClass();
request.get('pathtoapi').then(function(result) {
  myTestClass.paymentDate = result.payment.paymentDate
})
```

Answer (score 2):

you can wrap the response inside Date object

try

```
var responsePaymentDate = new Date(this.payment.paymentDate);
```

now you will be able to call get, set function on this object

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to avoid this extra conversions. I was hoping that there is possible to get correct value from the server at once.